# Como buscar por 2 campos en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de realizar una busqueda por 2 campos, ambos estan en la misma tabla, quiero buscar un dato capturado en la bd ya sea por el nombre del equipo que es lo que se captura o por la fecha de cuando se capturo.

Por ahora solo puedo buscar por un solo campo no logro hacer que busque por cualquiera de los 2, o busco por nombre o por fecha, esto es lo que tengo.

Esta es la function por la que mando los valores para que haga el select.

```
public function Buscar($campo_buscar, $datos_buscar)
{
    # code...
    $conexion = $this->getConection();

    $rows = array();
    if ($datos_buscar == '') {
        $query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * from " . $GLOBALS['tabla']);
    } else {
        $query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * from " . $GLOBALS['tabla'] . " WHERE " . $campo_buscar . " LIKE :b");
        $query->bindValue(':b', '%' . $datos_buscar . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    if (!$query) {
        return "Error al mostrar";
    } else {
        $query->execute();

        while ($result = $query->fetch()) {
            $rows[] = $result;
        }

        return $rows;
    }

    //$conexion->close();
}
```

Y aqui pongo los datos que quiero buscar, pero en este caso son 2 no es uno,

```
    // Buscar
$campo_buscar =  NombreEquipobd;
$datos_buscar= $_POST['txtBuscar'];


//Buscar
$campo_buscarfecha =  fechadeta;
$datos_buscartxtf = $_POST['txtfecha'];
```

Comment: Necesitas que el resultado coincida exactamente con los dos campos o con cualquiera de los dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola debes colocar un AND a tu sentencia:

```
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * from " . $GLOBALS['tabla'] . " WHERE " . $campo_buscar . " LIKE :b AND ".$datos_buscar." = '".$datos_buscartxtf."'");
```

Comment: Tenia pensado hacerlo de esa manera, pero no funciona, y en la parte AND $datos_buscar, va el campo por donde vas a buscar, aun asi no me funciono, se queda en blanco

Comment: Has un echo "<pre>"; var_dump($query); exit(); para ver la cadena del query y nos cuentas que obtienes

Comment: Van vacios los ultimos 2 datos, despues del AND

Comment: 'SELECT * from detalle_captura WHERE NombreEquipobd LIKE :b AND  = ''' (length=68)

Comment: ahí tienes el problema la variable $datos_buscartxtf esta vacía, trata de usar la sentencia OR si solo necesitas encontrar cualquiera de los campos

Comment: Lo utilice de la siguiente manera, en la funcion de buscar, puse la variable $campobuscarfecha = fechadeta; y la variable $datos_buscartxtf = $POST [txtfecha] y me muestra todos los datos como debe ser, pero se queda en blanco igual

Comment: `$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * from " . $GLOBALS['tabla'] . " WHERE " . $campo_buscar . " LIKE :b 
            OR ".$campo_buscarfecha." = '".$datos_buscartxtf."");`

Comment: A que te refieres con que se queda en blanco si también me dices que si te muestra los datos?  podrías colocar un ejemplo de lo que estas obteniendo para estar más claro

Comment: `public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * from detalle_captura WHERE NombreEquipobd LIKE :b 
            OR fechadeta = '08/08/2017'' (length=100)`

Comment: Lo tengo, se ponia en blanco por las comas simples al final, como en el echo var dump me mostraba 3 comas, pense que una sobraba, y la quitaba y la busqueda, cuando se hacia con LIKE lo unico que hacia era buscar parecidos, lo que me mandaba muchos resultados, utilice AND para definirlo mas y consegui filtrar los resultados, por fecha y nombre, en todo caso solo cambiara AND si es requerido que sean muy definidos o OR para que cualquiera de las 2 se cumplan.

Comment: Claro, que bueno que encontraste el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

debías de simplificar mas puedes eliminar linea de bindValue el por que? es simple por que estas realizando una búsqueda de con campo de textBuscar que es de tipo String y luego quieres realizar una búsqueda con txtfecha que es de tipo INT por lo tanto la restricción que le das de PDO::PARAM_STR no te daría buenos resultados, por lo tanto escribe directamente.

```
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * from ".$GLOBALS['tabla']." WHERE " . $campo_buscar." LIKE '%$datos_buscar%'");
```

Comment: Gracias, y es verdad tenia un string, ya que solo buscaba por nombres, lo cambie pero aun sigue buscando unicamente por nombres, trate de poner OR y AND pero no funciono o lo hice mal.

Answer (score 1):

Usa UNION para buscar varios valores en el mismo campo de la table

ejem

```
$sql = '';
$count = 0;
foreach($search as $text)
{
  if($count > 0)
     $sql = $sql."UNION Select name From myTable WHERE Name LIKE '%$text%'";
  else
     $sql = $sql."Select name From myTable WHERE Name LIKE '%$text%'";

  $count++;
}
```